# Splitting a String into a Vector C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have been working on the following piece of code; It opens an inputfile, reads the input, and now I wish to take that input (stored in a string) and split it by whitespaces; inputting each element into an integer vector.

I understand how to typecast. The problem is in the splitting. How do I do this efficiently? I would like to use a while loop or for loop except I am unable to index the string. I converted the string to constant char so I could index it but now I am unable to compare the value at a point in the string to the expression " " in my if statement. What should I do?

Comment: Why can't you index the string? What did you try as std::string does have indexing functions

Comment: Idk Visual Studio flipped out at me when I tried

Comment: First, starting your question with "I have been working on the following piece of code" and subsequently not providing any isn't helpful. Second, perhaps compare against a *single char* `' '` rather than a string literal `" "`, or better still, use `isdigit()` or `isspace()`, or even using a `istrstream` to format them into `int` values.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the current symbol to ' '.